# I am trying to automate a react page using selenium java. dropdown filed which i want to load a value from my input json file, how to achieve this?

Tags: json, data-driven-tests

Below is my json file

{

"orgName": "CTS",
"stateId": "Dubai"

}

but drop down field is not taking the value "Dubai" from json.. Please someone solve this

```
String org = (String) organization.get("orgName");
        String dd = (String) organization.get("stateId");
                                    
        WebElement orgN = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='orgName']"));
        orgN.sendKeys(org);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        WebElement drop = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=' css-14cdt5o-control']"));
        Select dropdown = new Select(drop);
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText(dd);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXbvg.png)